# Using other block device when conecting Android device to computer as USB storage

Tags: sd-card, usb-connection-mode

When I connect the device to computer, it makes sdcard available to it, as in card reader.

How to make it share not sdcard, but other block device or file?

Comment: I would assume that this is highly hardware dependent and impossible without writing and replacing drivers, at best.

Comment: How it works? How to make "Use USB connection to transfer files" action manually, from console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my device (Sony Ericsson Xperia X10) it is, for example:

```
echo /sdcard/debian.ext2 > /sys/devices/platform/msm_hsusb/gadget/lun0/file
```

After it the content of file becomes available on the host. Can write to sdcard file without unmounting it from android.